# Trying to install Docker-CE on Linux Mint 17.03 - E: Unable to locate package docker-ce

Tags: docker, linux-mint

I'm trying to install Docker on Linux Mint 17.03. When I follow the steps on the Docker [website](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#upgrade-docker-after-using-the-convenience-script), I get until the step:

sudo apt-get install docker-ce

This produces the error "E: Unable to locate package docker-ce"

The steps I performed so far are:

```
sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install \
apt-transport-https \
ca-certificates \
curl \
software-properties-common

curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -

sudo add-apt-repository \ "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \ $(lsb_release -cs) \ stable"

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install docker-ce
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought it's worth documenting that after following about every tutorial I could find on the internet to no avail, the command that made it work was:

```
sudo add-apt-repository    "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \ trusty \ stable"
```

Replacing $(lsb_release -cs) by only "trusty"

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command on your terminal.

curl -sSL https://get.docker.com | sh

Comment: You should add `sudo`

Answer (score 0):

You can manually update your software sources, so you can find the ubuntu version that contains docker-ce, in my case was tara(mint 19) , I changed for bionic (ubuntu); When typing 'sudo apt-get install docker TAB', docker-ce appear and can be installed.

[image]